# mysql SET sql_mode = '' to fix strict mode errors in mysql 5.7 and mysql 8

Tags: mysql

If I do `SET sql_mode = ''` what are the side effects in mysql 5.6, 5.7 and 8? It seems to fix strict errors in >=5.7 but I want to know if it can cause any configuration errors with replication or not be supported by some setups of php/mysql

Comment: `''` SQL mode mainly makes code maintenance harder. Simple design errors go unnoticed, there's a risk of data loss due to truncation, you need to take `0000-00-00 00:00:00` into account in every query... that kind of stuff. However, if an application relies on those errors being possible (for instance, it inserts rows with missing mandatory columns) it will break under different settings. So it isn't advisable to set it as system default if you need to run such kind of apps. As about MySQL itself, I presume it supports  strict mode but I don't have first hand experience with complex set-ups.

Comment: You're not "fixing" those errors, you're just sweeping them under the carpet. Listen to the advice MySQL gives and act on it.